# How to check amount of cached disk space used on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

So the OS basically removes all disk memory in the cached directory of apps when disk space runs low, is there any way of determining how much disk space is currently being used for cached data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You can never access the file system in general. And thus not the cache being used by other apps.

If you re-ask the question as "Is there any way to tell how much disk space **my app** is using in the cache, the answer is **yes**.

Walk the file system of your cache directory using `NSFileManager` and use `[NSFileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:error:]` to get the size of each file.